# My server doesn't support range header requests, does that mean it's impossible for me to implement resumable downloads?

Tags: ios, download, nsurlconnection, resume

I am currently developing an iPhone app, in which involves downloads of up to 300 mb.

I have been told by my hosting service that my server does not support range header requests. However, when I download a file from my server using a download client, like safari download manager, resume options are available and work.

Does this mean that they have a work around for servers that don't support range header requests and that I could possibly implement into my iPhone app? Or are they using a technique too complex to implement into the iPhone.

If you know of a technique code samples will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the connection from the download client encrypted? If not, sniff it with WireShark or tcpdump, and see what technique they're using.

Comment: @David Gelhar
I'm not at all familiar with those open source programs. I tried wire shark but got no where.